# Changed DB engine to MySQL. Now Django does not create tables

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration, django-database

I have a Django app with a standard sqlite3 DB. Now I want to use MySQL. So I changed my `DATABASES` in `settings.py`, and it works well, but I can't run server because it says

```
django.db.utils.InternalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'django'")
```

So I created this DB in the client, and now it says

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'django.Cat' doesn't exist")
```

Seems like I have to create all tables by myself, which is the worst variant I can do.

```
#settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/path/to/db.conf',
        },
    }
}
```

and

```
#conf.db
[client]
database = django
host = localhost
user = DjangoUser
password = password_you_cant_guess
default-character-set = utf8
```

How to make Django create all tables I have?

I even can't run `python3 manage.py` with any command because it gives my this exception.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'django.Cat' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/path/to/project/External/apps.py", line 13, in ready
    active_cats = list(Cat.objects.filter(active_cat=True).all())
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1151, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'django.Cat' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Did you create the database `django` in your MySQL instance? It doesn't exist unless you create it. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-database.html

Comment: @BillKarwin, yes, I did. As I say in the question, I created it, and then I got `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'django.Cat' doesn't exist")`. Do I really have to create all the tables?

Comment: You have to create the database in the respective DB engine. Django won't do that

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, please, read the comment I wrote :)

Comment: You don't need to create *tables*, but the database

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, I created the database. As I said in the question `So I created this DB in the client, and now it says`

Comment: @Mattern once you created the database and made sure you can connect to it (and have the required privileges on the database), you have to run your migrations to create the tables.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, unfortunately, as I said in the question, `I even can't run python3 manage.py with any command because it gives my this exception`, so I can not make any migrations, but connection seems working because i had different exceptions

Comment: @Mattern mmm yes indeed - but this means you're trying to access this table (model) before django has finished loading apps etc. Check your traceback (which you should have included) for what is leading to this behaviour.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I added the traceback. Seems like mysql asks me to create the table by myself, I have no other ideas :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
File "/path/to/project/External/apps.py", line 13, in ready
    active_cats = list(Cat.objects.filter(active_cat=True).all())
```

This code is executed as part of the initialization process. This is what prevents you from executing any management command. Note that [this is documented with a very clear warning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready):

> Warning
>
> Although you can access model classes as described above, **avoid
>   interacting with the database in your ready() implementation**. This
>   includes model methods that execute queries (save(), delete(), manager
>   methods etc.), and also raw SQL queries via django.db.connection. Your
>   ready() method will run during startup of every management command.
>   For example, even though the test database configuration is separate
>   from the production settings, manage.py test would still execute some
>   queries against your production database!

Comment: Well, you are right, but there are 2 questions:
 1. Why it was working with sqlite?
 2. I need to make some changes to db before the server starts running, so, what to i do instead the problem you find out? :)

Comment: 1/ because you added this code after you ran the migrations creating the table (hint: it's a good thing to regularly check you can run all your migrations on a new empty database).

Comment: 2/ "server start" doesn't mean much - in production, Django apps are typically run as multiple concurrent processes, which are handled by your front server wsgi bridge (apache mod_wsgi, gunicorn or whatever). Actually it's impossible to answer this question without knowing exactly what you want to do here and why (beware of [xy problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)).

Comment: I used to do something similar in `Flask` app. My app runs some other scripts, they can long up to day, so if server crashes for some reason I need to mark them on the next server startup that they were failed. This variant was ok in `Flask`, but seems it won't work there

Comment: You may want to use an async task queue then - your "other scripts" should not depend on the wsgi server processes lifetime. But once again, without a __clear__ problem statement (=> in a new question), it's impossible to provide any serious help. The fact that "ir worked ok on Flask" (actually I'd say "seemed to work ok so far" - quite a lot of things seem to work ok until your app goes in production with some real traffic and load) doesn't mean it was the best solution anyway.

Comment: Well, thanks for the help and advises! Have a nice day :)